# Conditional formatting text contains plus sign (+)

Tags: google-sheets, escaping, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I would like to conditionally format a cell if it contains a plus sign (+).  Simply putting a `+` in the value box errors with *Invalid formula*. `'+` doesn't work either.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `+` with a swung dash (tilde) `~` prefix.